# Why did my desk lamp flicker after being turned off for a while?

Tags: lighting, light

Once when I turned off the desk lamp and went to sleep, it suddently started to flicker drastically and would not stop. So I could only get up and turn off the switch of the plug, the flickering stopped immediately. This has never happened before.

I tried to recreate the same thing in the next morning, but did not manage to.

Does anyone know what might have caused this?

I am not sure what kind of lightbulb does my lamp has (it was from previous tenant), it might be energy-saving lightbulb.

Pictures of my lamp:
[image]

When it is switched on:
[image]

Profile when it is switched on:
[image]

Comment: nobody knows what caused it ... we can only guess what might have caused it ... maybe the switch is failing

Comment: Another vote for the switch failing. The switch is supposed to stop electricity flowing through it when it's turned off, but apparently it didn't. You were right to unplug it, since this can cause the switch to overheat.

Comment: Well, if  you don't know anything about the light, then you can't honestly expect us to be able to tell you much about why.  I'm sorry but I must VTC for lack of actionable information (which really is a lack of effort on your part). Please [edit] relevant info in; I will retract if you do.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the light bulb? We might be able to work out what type of bulb it is from a photo

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Thank you for your suggestion. I just added photos of the light bulb.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I just added photos of the light bulb. I hope it would be sufficient for you.